# Default values of class variables

Tags: c#, class

Today i read an answer in this site. 
[MVC ViewModel - Object Reference Not Set to Instance of an Object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15731452/1628636)

I'm confused about default values of instanced classes. When we create a new class by using "new" keyword, its fields's values automatically setted to their default values.

For example integers goes to 0 and strings goes to null.

What about the Lists?

```
List<int>
```

Why we dont have new instance of the List belong to the instanced object?

Comment: strings will be `null`, not `""`.

Comment: If you want your class members to default to something else every time you declare an instance of a class, you can do so in the constructor of the class.

Answer (score 8):

> Why we dont have new instance of the List belong to the instanced object?

[As per the C# specification, ECMA-334, section 12.2:](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf)

> The following categories of variables are automatically initialized to their default values:
>   - Static variables
>   - Instance variables of class instances
>   - Array elements
>
> The default value of a variable depends on the type of the variable and is determined as follows:
>   - For a variable of a value-type, the default value is the same as the value computed by the value-type's default constructor.
>   - **For a variable of a reference-type, the default value is null.**

Refer to the bolded excerpt above - since `List<int>` is a reference type, it is therefore initialized to `null`.

Answer (score 5):

A `List<T>` where T is any type is a reference type. Hence, it's default value is null.

For instance let that we have the following class declaration:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName  { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

where Order is a class.

If you instantiate an object of type customer like below:

```
var customer = new Customer();
```

Then

```
customer.Id // is 0
customer.FirstName // is null
customer.LastName // is null
customer.Orders // is null
```

Note that both `FirstName` and `LastName` are strings and their default value is null. Strings are reference types.